# Swift with Electron on macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, electron

Is it possible to invoke and debug swift code in an [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app?

For my particular case, I'd like to change the background of my screen.

```
let sharedWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
let mainScreen = NSScreen.mainScreen()
let url = NSURL(string: "path/to/my/image")!
do {
    try sharedWorkspace.setDesktopImageURL(url, forScreen: mainScreen!, options: [:])
} catch {
    print (error)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, but you could compile it to a binary and spawn it from Electron using [`child_process.execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback).

There also exist a node module that does what you're trying to achieve: [`wallpaper`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/wallpaper)